# How to add class to second main div element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML in my page

```
<td id="tdCase" colspan="4" rowspan="2">
    <div style="width: 100px;" unselectable="on">
        <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);" class=" nicEdit-panelContain" unselectable="on">              
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100px; border-color: currentcolor rgb(204, 204, 204) rgb(204, 204, 204); border-style: none solid solid; border-width: 0px 1px 1px; border-image: none 100% / 1 / 0 stretch; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">        
        <div>
            <div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>       
</td>
```

In my td element I have 2 main div elements and those two main div elements have some inner elements.
Here I want to add a class to my second div element using jQuery.

Comment: Use `id`s to make the `div`s distinguishable from each other.

Comment: div elements are coming through online, we have only td element in out html page

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
$('#tdCase > div:eq(1)').addClass('something')
```

You use `:eq(1)` since the indices are zero-based.

Comment: @srinivaschalla Then you'll need to provide a [mcve] showing the issue since this works fine